# Scan all beans as if they were in the current package in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot parent project which I'm using as a dependency for customer-specific extending projects. Initially, to make sure everything else was working correctly, I set the base package for the customer project to be the same as the parent project and everything worked as expected. Once I added the Application class to a sub-package however, I started getting exceptions about missing beans and components.

For an example, the parent project has base package com.example.parent and the customer project has base package com.example.parent.customerA. At first, none of the parent beans were getting picked up, so I added `@ComponentScan("com.example.parent")`. I then got an exception about a missing repository bean, so I added `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.parent")`. I then got an exception about a missing entity, so I added `@EntityScan("com.example.parent")`, and now it's running like it was when the customer project had the same package as the parent.

**Is there are a cleaner way to load all the parent project's beans and components?** I'd rather have a way to configure the customer project so that everything in the parent project is loaded as if the customer project had the same base package. I'm worried that if I had to add these specific annotations for jpa repos and entities, I might not have all my bases covered with some kind of other Spring object that might be added in the future.

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.parent"})` should scan all components (Controller,Repository,Service) in this package as well as its subpackage. Can you post your config Class

Comment: It didn't pick up the repos and entities

Comment: Please post your config class. please paste the code which i wrote for component scan. Entities are used for persisting in database and their scan should be set in hibernate or JPA config classes

Answer (score 4):

The cleaner approach is what Alex mentioned. But if you really need your spring boot application to reside in a subpackage, you can define the base packages in the @SpringBootApplication as follows.

```
package com.example.parent.customer


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.parent"})
public class SpringBootApp {
//main method
}
```

In this way, different projects can share common spring beans and have specific components within its subpackage.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way for me is to have my spring boot Application reside at the root of all the beans I wish to be discovered (a.k.a. `com.example.parent` or even `com.example` if it applies). So, In your case, I would have

```
package com.example.parent //or com.example

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {
    //main method
}
```

By default, everything in the current package and sub-packages will be picked up. This works because `@SpringBootApplication` already defines a `@ComponentScan`, with no args, which defaults to the current package.

[Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class):

> We generally **recommend that you locate your main application class in
>   a root package above other classes**. The @EnableAutoConfiguration
>   annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly
>   defines a base “search package” for certain items. For example, if you
>   are writing a JPA application, the package of the
>   @EnableAutoConfiguration annotated class will be used to search for
>   @Entity items.
>
> Using a root package also allows the @ComponentScan annotation to be
>   used without needing to specify a basePackage attribute. You can also
>   use the @SpringBootApplication annotation if your main class is in the
>   root package.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. I thought there might be a benefit to having an individual spring boot application class for each of the customer projects, but I don't think there's a point